# Creating new clickable button to perform certain actions on Github Pull Request

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am attempting to implement a mechanism to achieve the following,

When a Pull request is raised in GitHub, a Jenkins job will be triggered => This is already implemented.

New requirements to be implemented:

1. When the above Jenkins build fails, a new clickable button needs to be created and enabled on the Pull request
2. Upon clicking the button some actions needs to be performed.

Need any sample code or ways to implement it.
Need the complete workflow guide on how to add this button, where to add the code and how to make the button appear on the PR all these details as I am new to GitHub.